# Does a runnable in a service run on the UI thread

Tags: android, runnable

In Android, when I create a runnable inside a service and run it, while I realize it runs in its own thread, is this thread somehow part of the UI thread? In other words, if the runnable carried out a long process, would it affect the UI?

**EDIT:**

```
private class SomeRunnable implements Runnable
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    try
    {

    }
  }
}

SomeRunnable runnable = new SomeRunnable();
(new Handler()).postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```

Comment: depends how you run it.

Comment: Your assumption "...while I realize it runs in its own thread..." is not true. A `Runnable` can run anywhere, it depends on where you run it. For example, if you simply create a `Handler` in your `Service` and then post your `Runnable` using the `Handler`, it will run on the main (UI) thread.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Using this code your `Runnable` is running on the main (UI) thread. If this `Runnable` takes a long time, you run the risk of having your app force-closed with an ANR (Application Not Responsing) error.

Comment: Would I be better off to run it in an AsyncTask or will I still end up with the same problem?

Comment: If all you want to do is run the `Runnable` in a separate Thread, you don't need `AsyncTask`. Just do: `new Thread(new SomeRunnable()).start();`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Docs:

> A services runs in the same process as the application in which it is
>   declared and in the main thread of that application,

Different thread:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
t.start();
```

UI/Service Thread:

```
Handler h = new Handler();
h.post(new MyRunnable());
```

Comment: But that refers to a service. My question is about launching a runnable from a service.

Comment: @AndroidDev The first piece of code launches a `Runnable` on a separate thread, **completely unrelated to UI thread**. The second piece of code runs the `Runnable` on **same thread** on which service is running, and it **will effect UI thread**.

Comment: I am launching it with a Handler, so according to you, it must be running on the UI thread.

Comment: @AndroidDev In case of handler,  it will run on thread which executed `new Handler()` like you created handler in `onBind()` of service, that handler points to service thread now.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not part of `UI thread`, I assume by `Runnable` you mean a new thread that you execute by calling `start()`.

Regardless if you start a new `Thread` in a `service` or `activity` it will *not* be part of the UI thread (unless you call something like `join()`)

**Edit**

Since you are running a `Runnable` object with `Handler`, so it depends on where you *initialize* your `handler`. Service runs in the `main thread`, so initializing the handler in a service or activity will make the code be posted to the `UI thread`

Note, you need a single `Handler` object per your thread; so avoid creating a new one with every time e.g. `(new Handler()).postDelayed(runnable, 1000);` should be avoided and instead `handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);` where `handler` is an instance variable initialized in your service/activity class

Comment: User117 seems to indicate otherwise. Are you sure?

Comment: Your question needs more clarification, what exactly you mean by `Runnable`. I mentioned it clearly if you start a new `Thread` by calling `start()`, it will be different from the `UI Thread`

Comment: See the code I added above in my original post. There is no start.

Comment: I have never heard of running a Runnable with start. I am only familiar with runOnUiThread and using a Handler. I am familiar with starting Threads with start() however.

Comment: I don't use (new Handler()). I only posted that to show I use a Handler. I do in fact only create the handler once and it's a private member.

Answer (score 0):

By default services runs in UI thread. But it depends on service type and service properties and the way you post runnable. I think that you use default scheme and your runnable will be executed on UI thread and block it.

If you show code how you post runnable and create service I can give you exact answer.

You can check thread type from your runnable using following code:

```
if (Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread()) {
    // On UI thread.
} else {
    // Not on UI thread.
}
```

It is still not clear. If you execute "new Handler()" on UI thread than runnable will be executed on UI thread. If you execute "new Handler()" on another thread with looper than runnable will be executed on that thread. I think with probability 99% your runnable will be executed on UI thread. Why don't you place my code in runnable and check where it is executed?

Comment: I see conflicting responses posted here. Some seem to say yes and others say no.

Comment: @AndroidDev Yes, because there are different ways to "create a `Runnable`". If you will update your post with the code you use to "create a `Runnable`" then we can probably give you a better answer.

Comment: See my comment to your question. That `Runnable` runs on the main (UI) thread.

Answer (score 0):

The runnable you submit to your handler will be always executed on the UI thread, since service are not spawn on a different process or threda, but thy are part of hte  UI thread